# Replace all negative integers with 0 recursively in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to replace any negative integers with 0 in an array. However, I cannot quite figure out what to do from here. I know that my replace method is not correct, but this is what I've tried so far.

```js
function substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex) {
  if (currentIndex < array.length) {
    if (array[currentIndex] < 0) {
      array[currentIndex] = 0;
    }

    return substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex + 1);
  }
};

console.log(substitute_negatives([2, -1, 3, -1, 2], 0));
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this problem. Is this possible to also do with a linked list recursively?

Comment: also there's nothing naturally recursive about this; it's a simple traversal of an array. Why do you want to do it with recursion?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the negative numbers with 0's. I've changed it to be recursive but I feel like I'm getting more lost.

Comment: also also your function doesn't return a value, so the `console.log()` will print `undefined`

Comment: @SharonKaufman Your edit fixed one issue, then the core issue still remains: arrays are zero-indexed so `array.length` is always one larger than the highest index, so it is always `undefined`. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the recursion finishes, you actually need to return the array, so you have to call `return array` instead of an empty `return` statement.

Also, if `currentIndex` is greater than `array.length`, then it is too late because arrays are zero-indexed, thus the `undefined`. Try using greater-than or equals to.

Try this instead:

```js
function substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex = 0) {
  if (currentIndex >= array.length) return array;
  if (array[currentIndex] < 0) array[currentIndex] = 0;
  return substitute_negatives(array, currentIndex+1);
}

console.log(substitute_negatives([2, -1, 3, -1, 2]));
```

Note that in the real world, use `.map()` instead:

```js
const substitute_negatives = (arr) => arr.map(x => x < 0 ? 0 : x);

console.log(substitute_negatives([2, -1, 3, -1, 2]));
```

Comment: Wow @Michael M., thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. It makes more sense now. Also, that map object makes it waaaay more understandable. Great tip! Thank you!!